# Schema error when reusing same field

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I have two separate schemas that use the same field. I've tried to create schemaComponents so that I can update both schemas in one location however I get an error `Error: Invalid definition for school.$ field`. when I use it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I was under the impression this was allowed.

Path: `SchemaComponents.js`

```
SchemaComponents = {
  schools: {
    type: [String],
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {label: "School One", value: 'SchoolOne'},
        {label: "School Two", value: 'SchoolTwo'},
        {label: "School Three", value: 'SchoolThree'},
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Path: `StudentSchema.js`

```
import from '../components/SchemaComponents.js';
StudentSchema = new Mongo.Collection("studentSchema");

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.StudentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    school: SchemaComponents.schools,
});

StudentSchema.attachSchema(Schemas.StudentSchema);
```

Path: `TeacherSchema.js`

```
import from '../components/SchemaComponents.js';
TeacherSchema = new Mongo.Collection("teacherSchema");

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.TeacherSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    school: SchemaComponents.schools,
});

TeacherSchema.attachSchema(Schemas.TeacherSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `SchemaComponent` as a simple *object* and not as a *SimpleSchema* object. To reuse your `schools` definition do:

```
let schoolsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  schools: {
    type: [String],
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {label: "School One", value: 'SchoolOne'},
        {label: "School Two", value: 'SchoolTwo'},
        {label: "School Three", value: 'SchoolThree'},
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can do:

```
Schemas.TeacherSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  school: {
    type: schoolsSchema
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting server error `ReferenceError: schoolsSchema is not defined` in the Path: `TeacherSchema.js`

Comment: Then you need to import `schoolsSchema` into your `TeacherSchema.js` file.

Comment: Ok, so I've add `import schoolsSchema from '../components/SchemaComponents.js';` now I'm getting `Error: Invalid definition for school field`

Comment: My apologies, forgot to include the type

Comment: OK, getting there. Thanks. Looks like there is one more issue. The `school: {type: schoolsSchema}` doesn't display any of the options. It's supposed to be a select dropdown that displays, school one, school two etc. None of that information is flowing through. There's also no errors.